# Is there any way to combine time and date in python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I have 2 functions which gives output as date and time

```
def jdtodatestd (jdate):
  if len(jdate) == 5:    
    fmt = '%y%j'
    datestd = datetime.datetime.strptime(jdate, fmt).date()
    return(datestd)
  elif len(jdate) == 6:
    yr = jdate[0:2]
    day = jdate[2:len(jdate)]
    day = day.lstrip('0')
    jdate = yr+day
    fmt = '%y%j'
    datestd = datetime.datetime.strptime(jdate, fmt).date()
    return(datestd)
  elif len(jdate) == 7:
    fmt = '%Y%j'
    datestd = datetime.datetime.strptime(jdate, fmt).date()
    return(datestd)
  
jdtodatestd('120365')
```

Output: datetime.date(2012, 12, 30)

```
def jdtotimestd (jtime):
  if len(jtime) == 5:
    jtime = '0' + jtime
  elif len(jtime) == 6:
    jtime = jtime
  else:
    jtime = '000000'
    
  stdtime = jtime[0:2] + ':' +  jtime[2:4]  + ':' + jtime[4:6]
  return stdtime
  
jdtotimestd('140932')
```

Output: '14:09:32'

I would like to combine both such as '2012, 12, 30 14:09:32

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your function `jdtotimestd`:

```
def jdtotimestd(jtime):
    """Returns a dt.time object from string."""
    jtime = jtime.zfill(6)
    return datetime.time(int(jtime[:2]), int(jtime[2:4]), int(jtime[4:]))

d = jdtodatestd('120365')
t = jdtotimestd('140932')

dt = datetime.datetime.combine(d, t)
```

Output:

```
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 30, 14, 9, 32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime` and `strptime`:

```
output1 = jdtodatestd('120365')
output2 = jdtotimestd('140932')

>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.strftime(output1, "%Y-%m-%d")+output2, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 30, 14, 9, 32)
```